# How would I add the second element of each item in a list?

Tags: java

I have created a new array list with company symbols followed by their stock prices. How could I add the total stock prices or the second element in each item of my array list:

```
 public class StockList
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      List<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<Stock>();
      
      stocks.add(new Stock("ATT", 190.25));
      stocks.add(new Stock("IBM", 65.75));
      stocks.add(new Stock("YAH", 220.50));
      stocks.add(new Stock("ALP", 800.25));
      stocks.add(new Stock("AMD", 12.53));
      
      // Display the elements in the List.
      System.out.println("Here is my portfolio:");
      for (Stock s : stocks)
         System.out.println(s);
    
      System.out.println("\nTotal price: $" + totalPrice(stocks));
   }

   public static double totalPrice(List<Stock> list)
   {
        
   }
  
   return ;
    }
```

Stock class. The equals method is something else that I am currently working on:

```
public class Stock
{
   private String symbol;     // Trading symbol of stock
   private double sharePrice; // Current price per share
     
   public Stock(String sym, double price)
   {
      symbol = sym;
      sharePrice = price;
   }
         
   public String getSymbol()
   {
      return symbol;
   }
   
   public double getPrice()
   {
      return sharePrice;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      String str = String.format("Trading symbol: %5s   Share price: $%7.2f", symbol, sharePrice);
      return str;
   }
 
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object other)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: What does your `Stock` class look like ?

Comment: @ChocolateGoosePoosey, have a look at my newly implemented and tested answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `getPrice()` method to get the price of individual stock.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Stock
{
    private String symbol;     // Trading symbol of stock
    private double sharePrice; // Current price per share
 
    public Stock(String sym, double price)
    {
        symbol = sym;
        sharePrice = price;
    }
            
    public String getSymbol()
    {
        return symbol;
    }
    
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return sharePrice;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str = String.format("Trading symbol: %5s   Share price: $%7.2f", symbol, sharePrice);
        return str;
    }

}

public class StockList{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<Stock>();
        
        stocks.add(new Stock("ATT", 190.25));
        stocks.add(new Stock("IBM", 65.75));
        stocks.add(new Stock("YAH", 220.50));
        stocks.add(new Stock("ALP", 800.25));
        stocks.add(new Stock("AMD", 12.53));
        
        // Display the elements in the List.
        System.out.println("Here is my portfolio:");
        for (Stock s : stocks)
            System.out.println(s);
        
        System.out.println("\nTotal price: $" + totalPrice(stocks));
    }

    public static double totalPrice(List<Stock> list){
    
        double total = 0.0;

        for (Stock s : list)
            total += s.getPrice();

        return total;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Here is my portfolio:
Trading symbol:   ATT   Share price: $ 190.25
Trading symbol:   IBM   Share price: $  65.75
Trading symbol:   YAH   Share price: $ 220.50
Trading symbol:   ALP   Share price: $ 800.25
Trading symbol:   AMD   Share price: $  12.53
Total price: $1289.28
```

Answer (score -1):

What you fetch in each iteration of your for-loop is simply an object of type Stock. Your Stock class has public methods defined(get and set methods) to fetch or update values of that particular object. In this case, you need to use the **getPrice** method to obtain the price of each stock object. Best way is to add the values to a variable as you iterate and return the variable at the exit of the for-loop.

```
public static double totalPrice(List<Stock> list){
        double totalPrice = 0.0;
        for (Stock s : list) // for each Stock object in your list
           totalPrice += s.getPrice(); // get the price value and add it to the totalPrice.
        }
        return totalPrice;
}
```

Comment: Any idea why it would say "cannot find symbol" for stocks in the line "for(Stock s : stocks)?

Comment: Have you imported the Stock class ?

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27301919).